# How to return mongodb user object who has player skill greater than 100 in an array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a user object goes like this:

```
{
    'name':'david'
    'players' :[{
         playerName : donny brasko,
         skill :100
     }
     ...
     ]
},
{
    'name':'danny'
    'players' :[{
         playerName : james joice,
         skill :110
     }
     ...
     ]
}
```

In robomongo i want to do a simple query like this:
return me the users objects of those who have players (in the inner array) with skill over 100.

What is the way to do so?

Comment: Your title and body of question are in conflict. Which do you want? A. All objects where a player skill is greater than 100? B. The highest skilled player within the array of each object?

Comment: all object where player skill greater

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you really need to do is test the value via ["dot notation":](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation)

```js
db.users.find({ "players.skill": { "$gt": 100 } })
```

And that filters out any users who do not have a player with a skill above that level.

If you want to "filter" the players themselves that are below that level, then use `.aggregate()` instead:

```js
db.users.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "players.skill": { "$gt": 100 }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "name": 1,
        "players": {
            "$setDifference": [
                { "$map": {
                    "input": "$players",
                    "as": "player",
                    "in": {
                        "$cond": [
                            { "$gt": [ "$$player.skill", 100 ] },
                            "$$player",
                            false
                        ]
                    }
                }},
                [false]
            ]
        }
    }}
])
```

And that not only selects the users with players with higher skill, but removes all players from the results with a lower skill as well.